# Strange cache behavior with Symfony2

Tags: php, css, caching, symfony

So I'm having a weird problem with Symfony's cache that seems to be triggered by the asset() function.

My template has this line: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('public/login/css/layouts.css') }}" />`

Changes to this CSS-file will not appear in the browser. I tried to clear browser cache, `rm -rf app/cache/*` and adding a version number to the link. Nothing did work.

When I change the link by simply removing the asset-function and directly link to the file, I see the changes. Changing the link back will show me the old css-file. What I don't understand is that the HTML-file that is sent to the browser is **exactly the same**. The link to the CSS-file does not change at all but the content in the CSS-file does change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your assets in a bundle and let Symfony handle them.
After a change, be sure to run:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't change anything. Also my environment is dev. The problem is not to see changes in prod, it's all about seeing them in dev.

Comment: assets:install is needed in dev too, but apparently it doesn't help. Do you see your layouts.css file appear in the output of this command?

Comment: Nope the layouts.css is not listed in the output. This is because it is not located in the bundle but in /web/public. Might this be the problem?

Comment: probably, you must work on files located in public folder. assetic will move them to the web folder when you run the assets:install command. i suggest you read a bit more on assets management: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: Ok I tried that and it seems to work. But why is this? This is not the perfect solution for me, because I use the template in several bundles. It's kind of a base view and I'd have to decide in which bundle I should put it.

What is asset doing there? I don't get it.

Comment: Does it work if you use this kind of path: <link href="{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/css/wallpaper.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />.This way, you just say in which bundle to look for the asset. Or if you want to go further, you could even use assetic and the {% stylesheets %} tag

Comment: Yes this works. The point is, I use this file in a base view (/app/Resources/views) and I don't to store it in some bundle, unrelated to the view.

Comment: Well, you can always save your file in some folder under web, and just call it with the link tag without using {{ asset_url }}, but this is against Symfony's spirit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18047/discussion-between-marronsuisse-and-entek)